# Protect form with session token

Tags: php, forms, token

I wrote a script to protect my form with session token; however my script does not work if I try to validate form fields before checking for the token. Would someone help me figure out what is wrong with my script please?

```
<?php
          session_start();
          class TOKEN {
            public static function generate() {
              return $_SESSION['token'] = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(15));
            }
            public static function check($token) {
              if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $token === $_SESSION['token']) {
                unset($_SESSION['token']);
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            }
          }
        ?>
        <?php
          $display_form = FALSE;
          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $userpass = $_POST['userpass'];

            if (strlen($username) < 4) {
              $error_name = 'required';
              $display_form = true;
              $validation_error = true;
            }
            if (strlen($userpass) < 8) {
              $error_pass = 'required';
              $display_form = true;
              $validation_error = true;
            }
            if (!$validation_error) {
              if (TOKEN::check($_POST['token'])) {
                echo 'process form';
              } else {
                echo 'invalid security token';
              }
            }
          } else {
            $display_form = TRUE;
          }
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
          if ($display_form == true) {
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo TOKEN::generate(); ?>">
          <input type="text" name="username" id="" placeholder="username">
          <?php echo $error_name; ?>
          <br>
          <input type="password" name="userpass" id="" placeholder="Password">
          <?php echo $error_pass; ?>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in">
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
         }
        ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked generated html? Have you checked `$_POST`?

Comment: Yes I did and the token is generated in the html. If I submit the form without any errors, it works. But if one or both fields are required and I fix the fields validation and then submit the form, it displays invalid security token.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the problem here is in the following.

1. You have token in the **form** and token in the **session**. They're equal.
2. When you fill the form with errors - your form loads again. But! In the **session** you have previous token, from point 1, and in the **form** you have new token.
3. You submit again and check different tokens.

So, the solution is to `unset` token **always**, no matter you have wrong or right values in the form.

**Update:**

I suppose it should be something like:

```
if (!$validation_error) {
  // here token will be removed in `TOKEN::check`
  if (TOKEN::check($_POST['token'])) {
    echo 'process form';
  } else {
    echo 'invalid security token';
  }
} else {
  // remove token implicitly
  TOKEN::remove();
}
```

And in `TOKEN`:

```
public static function check($token) {
  $result = false;

  if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    if ($token === $_SESSION['token']) {
      $result = true;
    }
    // if token set - remove it
    self::remove();
  }

  return $result;
}

public static function remove() {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}
```

Comment: u_mulder, you are absolutely correct, this is what is happening, would you please tell me where do I need to include the unset token? and is that what I should: unset($)SESSION['token']);

Comment: Still getting invalid security token after applying your solution above

Answer (score -1):

This code is very hard to read. I can't tell when if statements start and end. Also stop using classes for everything. Use procedural programming like a big boy.

Your issue is a simple one. `$validation_error` was not initialized in the outer scope. Meaning that it was not saved between if statments.

To fix this simply add `$validation_error = false` at the outer scope:

```
...
$display_form = FALSE;
$validation_error = false; // right here
          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $userpass = $_POST['userpass'];
            ...
```